# saving in the database after return user?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-allauth

here I use essentially Django cookie cutter, to be able to save with a custom shape sign I had to proceed in this way, it works, I'm not sure it's the right way to proceed but I only found this one. I also tested with def Signup() but no results But I realized that the user is not directly saved in the database for this test I put a timer between alt_user and alt_user.name . I noticed that User.object.get gives me the user and that I can modify the rest of the user's information. But when I look at my database, the user's backup is only done after the user returns. Is the user cached before the backup? The problem it poses and that after saving Alt_user.save() I send the id of the one if in a celery task for a longer calculation, thanks you in advance

```
User = get_user_model()

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    name = CharField( max_length=255)
    forename = CharField( max_length=255)
    street = CharField( max_length=255)
    street_number = IntegerField()
    city = CharField(max_length=255)
    country = CountryField().formfield()
    phone_number = IntegerField()
    date_of_birth = DateField()
    affiliate_link = IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()  # use this function for swapping user model

    def save(self, request):
        # Ensure you call the parent class's save.
        # .save() returns a User object.
        user = super(CustomSignupForm, self).save(request)
        alt_user = User.objects.get(pk=user.id)
        time.sleep(30)
        alt_user.name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        alt_user.forename = self.cleaned_data['forename']
        alt_user.street = self.cleaned_data['street']
        alt_user.street_number = self.cleaned_data['street_number']
        alt_user.city = self.cleaned_data['city']
        alt_user.country = self.cleaned_data['country']
        alt_user.phone_number = self.cleaned_data['phone_number']
        alt_user.date_of_birth = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
        alt_user.save()
        calculate_user_in_matrix.delay(alt_user.id)
        return user
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code runs in a database transaction. If your Celery worker picks up the task quickly, the transaction is not committed yet. The user you just created is not visible outside of the transaction until it is committed.

The solution is to use the [`django.db.transaction.on_commit`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#performing-actions-after-commit) hook:

```
from django.db import transaction

class CustomSignupForm(SignupForm):
    ...
    def save(self, request):
        ...
        alt_user.save()
        transaction.on_commit(calculate_user_in_matrix.s(alt_user.id).delay)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for taking the time to understand, I went to the #django channel to ask for help too and I could get the same answer as you:), I thought I wouldn't get an answer here because I explained myself like a Spanish cow.

Comment: I think you explained yourself just fine, or my understanding of Spanish cows is much better than expected ;)